# Order by with formatted dates, doing it right?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I wanted a mere sanity check because I have a slight feeling I am doing it all wrong. I stripped down the use case to a very simple sample.

When formatting a date I need to cast the data in the order clause to avoid sorting a varchar object. However. Initially I expected the ORDER clause to function with a basic CONVERT(DATE, OrderDate). However it throws a clear exception "Column "OrderDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

It doesn't throw this error if I fully replicate the formatting. To me making no sense at all first having to format the date, and then cast it back.

Works fine but feels awkward having to format in the order clause

```
SELECT FORMAT (OrderDate,'MMM dd yyyy') AS OrderDate, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY FORMAT (OrderDate, 'MMM dd yyyy')
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, FORMAT (OrderDate,'MMM dd yyyy')) ASC
```

Doesn't work

```
SELECT FORMAT (OrderDate,'MMM dd yyyy') AS OrderDate, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY FORMAT (OrderDate, 'MMM dd yyyy')
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, OrderDate) ASC
```

Am I doing this correct though?

Comment: Honestly, formatting the date at all.in the RDBMS is the wrong idea; that's something for the presentation layer to do. Worry about the formatting in the application and use date on tic to get the date values. If `OrderDate` is a date and time data type, then just cast it to a `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function in the `ORDER BY` clause, so you don't need to convert the string back to a date:

```
SELECT FORMAT(OrderDate,'MMM dd yyyy') AS OrderDate, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY FORMAT(OrderDate, 'MMM dd yyyy')
ORDER BY MIN(OrderDate)
```

Comment: Ok, clear. I knew my approach was off somewhere. This helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the original column:

```
ORDER BY MIN(o.OrderDate)
```

Don't start playing with converting dates to strings and back to dates, if you don't have to.